# AnythingSlider is undefined

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I'm using the AnythingSlider jquery plugin for a photogallery and I'm having some problems in customizing it.

The slider works, but right now I want to show the current slide number and the total number and I'm getting an error in Firebug.

The script is this:

```
$(function() {

var current = $('#gallery').data('AnythingSlider').currentPage;
var pages = $('#gallery').data('AnythingSlider').pages;
$('.slides').append(current + '/' + pages);

$('#gallery').anythingSlider({
    appendBackTo: '.arrow-left',
appendForwardTo: '.arrow-right',
buildNavigation: false,
buildStartStop: false,
easing: 'linear',
resizeContents: false
    //expand: true
})
});
```

Without the first 3 lines it works, but with that Firebug says $("#gallery").data("AnythingSlider") is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `data('AnythingSlider')` is not available before the plugin initialization, so just place your following lines

```
var current = $('#gallery').data('AnythingSlider').currentPage;
var pages = $('#gallery').data('AnythingSlider').pages;
$('.slides').append(current + '/' + pages);
```

bottom of these lines

```
$('#gallery').anythingSlider({
    appendBackTo: '.arrow-left',
    appendForwardTo: '.arrow-right',
    buildNavigation: false,
    buildStartStop: false,
    easing: 'linear',
    resizeContents: false
   //expand: true
});
```

If everything else is right then it should work. `data('AnythingSlider')` will be available only when the plugin will be initialized because these data will be added by this plugin and until then these data are `undefined`.

Comment: thanks, this solved the problem. I was pretty sure I had tried that, but I was wrong. thanks again